# How to remove four nested "for" loops for this code in MATLAB. Any suggestions?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, nested

The code works very slow when the matrix dimension of (u,v) and (x,y) goes over (200,200). Here for simplicity I have considered both to be (3*3)

```
x1=1;y1=1;u1=1;v1=1;

        for u = -1:1:1
             for v = -1:1:1

                for x = -1:1:1
                  for y = -1:1:1

                    value(x1,y1) = exp( ( -1i*(((u-x)^2) + (v-y)^2))
                    y1 = y1+1;
                  end
                   x1 = x1+1;
                   y1 = 1;
                end
            S_rows = sum(value,2); %Adding components of matrix "value"
            S_complete = sum(S_rows);
            E2(u1,v1) = S_complete; 
                 x1 = 1;
                 v1 = v1 + 1;
              end
                u1 = u1+1;
                v1 = 1;
         end
```

Comment: in one word `meshgrid` ....

Comment: Hello, I tried using meshgrid. But thats not helping.
function [E2] = trial_200(focal_length)

%k = (2*pi)/wavelength;


[X,U] = meshgrid(-1:1);
[V,Y] = meshgrid(-1:1);

C = cat(4,U,V,X,Y);
Am = exp((-1i*(U-X).^2)/(2*focal_length));
Bm = exp((-1i*(V-Y).^2)/(2*focal_length));
A = Am(:);
B = Bm(:);
%disp(A)
%disp(B)
E = repmat(A,1,9);
disp(E)
E2 = E*B;
disp(E2)

Comment: Or [u, v, x, y] = ndgrid(-1:1, -1:1, -1:1, -1:1);